# Batch Consumer Dropping Elements

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a `BatchConsumer` that takes a number of items then invokes a callback.

```
public class BatchConsumer<T> {

  private List<T> storage = new ArrayList<>();

  private final Consumer<List<T>> callback;
  private final int batchSize;
  private final ExecutorService executor;

  public BatchConsumer(int batchSize, Consumer<List<T>> batchConsumer, ExecutorService executor) {
    this.batchSize = batchSize;
    this.callback = batchConsumer;
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  /**
   * Inserts an object. When {@link BatchConsumer#batchSize} objects have been inserted, the
   * callback will be invoked on the batch inside the executor.
   *
   * @param object
   */
  public synchronized void insert(T object) {
    storage.add(object);

    if (storage.size() == batchSize) {
      executor.submit(
          new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
              callback.accept(Collections.unmodifiableList(storage));
            }
          });

      storage = new ArrayList<>();
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I inspect the passed `storage` object inside the `batchConsumer` callback it never has `batchSize` elements. Typically it has between 1/3-2/3'rds as many as it should.

I think this is a simply concurrency issue that I am missing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not dropping elements, you are dropping the list completely. The anonymous inner class is referencing the enclosing class member variable. Any changes you make to that variable is visible in the inner class. After you submit the inner class, you change `storage`, and then when the inner class runs, it sees the modified version of the `storage`.

Declare a final variable before submitting, assign it to `storage`, and use that final variable in the inner class so you can use the version of `storage` you need.

Comment: I went for a walk just now and came to the same conclusion. Very silly lack of understanding around captures. Thanks.

Comment: Closures, like many other things, have not been incorporated into the language correctly. It is getting increasingly difficult to write maintainable programs with Java.